# Pandas column names begin from index column when running on visual code jupyter environment

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

[image]

I have written a very simple code that creates a pandas data frame. The issue is when I do my column naming ['X','Y'], my column heading X passes itself on to the column containing the index values. This only occurs when you run the code in jupyter environment, initiated in visual code by #%%. When you run the same code in the terminal the results are accurate. Shown in image below. Any ideas why?

```
#%%
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
data_1 = {'X': [1.0,2.0,3.0], 'Y': [1.0,2.5,3.5]}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1)
print(df_1)
```

I have also tried other methods, but the result is the same

```
data_1 = [(1.0,1.0),(2.0,2.5),(3.0,3.5)]
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1, columns = ['X','Y']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the default of the plugin and affects only visually... does not affect the functionallity

[image: example]

Comment: Aight thanks. Well, I first thought it was producing two lines because its thinking x-axis to be index column and the other two columns as perhaps Y1, Y2. But it seems not to be the case. I guess I'll just have to remove that index column

Comment: I don't see this as a problem, but yes... if you remove the index you will "solve" that. Please, don't forget to mark the right answer